# python + selenium + proxy + cert authorization problem

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, certificate, mitmproxy

Windows 10 + local account.
Edge 120.0.2210.77
Internet via proxy, login/pass auth required, certificate for proxy antivirus required.
Internet works well, except i can't run python/selenium script.
Microsoft Edge WebDriver 120.0.2210.144

This code

```
from selenium import webdriver
edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://mylogin:mypassword@192.168.34.195:3128");
RR = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options) **## Exception on this string**
```

rises exception

```
Exception managing MicrosoftEdge: error sending request for url (https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/LATEST_RELEASE_120_WINDOWS): error trying to connect: proxy authentication required
Error sending stats to Plausible: error sending request for url (https://plausible.io/api/event): error trying to connect: proxy authentication required
exception <class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException'>
    description:    Message: Unable to obtain driver for MicrosoftEdge using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

I see obvios reason: i didn't specify certificate location, but i don't know khow to do it.

I.e. to get pip works i should run

```
pip list --outdated --proxy http://mylogin:mypassword@192.168.34.195:3128 --cert c:\0.crt
```

Env var SE_PROXY=http://mylogin:mypassword@192.168.34.195:3128 doesn't help.
This code

```
PROXY = "<HOST:PORT>"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.EDGE['proxy'] = {
"httpProxy": PROXY,
"ftpProxy": PROXY,
"sslProxy": PROXY,
"proxyType": "MANUAL",

}
```

doesn't help too.

I'd prefer to disable selenium manager - is it possible?